# How to make a table responsive using CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design, datatables

I have design list of product using table and also use jQuery datatable feature
I want to make table responsive using CSS.
Please help me how to make a table responsive using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add the class "responsive" to the table element and reference this DataTables plugin .css:
https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css

You can see the example here: https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/initialisation/className.html